# using str_replace before simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using the simple HTML dom to grab scraped data and it's been working well.  However, one of the source I have doesn't have any unique fields so I'm trying to str_replace and then grab the elements that I've renamed and then use simple_html_dom.

However, it doesn't work.  my code is:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.url.com');

$html = str_replace('<strong>','',$html);

$html = str_replace('</strong>','',$html);   

$html = str_replace('<span class="pound">&pound;</span>','',$html);

$html = str_replace('<td>','<td class="myclass">',$html);

foreach($html->find('td.myclass') as $element)
   $price = $element->innertext;

$price = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $price);

echo $price;
```

Comment: You need to do your string replacements before you load the HTML into a DomDocument

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
  require('simple_html_dom.php');
  // Create DOM from URL or file
  $html = file_get_html( 'http://www.url.com' );

  foreach( $html->find( 'td' ) as $element ) {
    $price  = trim( str_replace( "&pound;", "", $element->plaintext ) );
  }

  $price = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $price);

  echo $price;
?>
```